# How can I stop Matlab rounding decimals when subtracting Datetime variables

Tags: matlab, datetime, precision

I am having some issues in Matlab to do with rounding errors with datetime typed variables.

I have an array, lets call it '`t`', and it is of type datetime. 
Say for example, `t(2) = 00:01:35.6889999`, and `t(1) = 00:01:35.3549042`.

If I try to do `t(2)-t(1)`, all I get is an answer of type 'duration' of `00:00:00` .

I would like to find the difference between these times and keep the precision! 
Any help, or directions to links that directly cater/relate to an issue like this would be appreciated! I'm not that familiar with using datetime & duration typed variables in Matlab!

Extra info: I am using Matlab R2017a

Edit: I have `Format Long;` written in my script.

Comment: Have you tried the command `format long`?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I should have mentioned that! I have it written in the second line of my script before anything happens.

Comment: Change the [`Format` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html#inputarg_displayFormat) of your duration object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision is not being lost, you just need to change the [display format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html#inputarg_displayFormat).

The default display format is `HH:MM:SS`:

```
>> A = duration(0, 0, 0, 1.25) % 1.25 MS

A = 

  duration

   00:00:00
```

You can modify the format to display fractional parts. For example:

```
>> A.Format = 's'  % Seconds only

A = 

  duration

   0.00125 sec

>> A.Format = 'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS'  % HMS, up to 9 fractional second digits

A = 

  duration

   00:00:00.00125000
```

You can also use helper functions like [`milliseconds`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/milliseconds.html) or [`seconds`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/seconds.html) to return `double` arrays:

```
>> seconds(A)

ans =

    0.0013

>> milliseconds(A)

ans =

    1.2500
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if only seconds vary in the two dates

```
second(t(1))-second(t(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The duration object actually has the proper precision. It just doesn't display it unless you set the format.

```
>> dur = duration(t(2) - t(1), 'Format', 's')
dur = 
  duration
   0.3341 sec
```

Whether you set the format or not, you can grab the seconds directly from the duration object.

```
>> format long
>> seconds(dur)
ans =
   0.334095700000000
>> seconds(t(2) - t(1))
ans =
   0.334095700000000
```